# How can I capture Release details and view them at Run Time?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a React SPA app with a .NET Core API, deploying through Azure DevOps to an Azure App Service.

I'd like to somehow capture the Release Name, and the Build Number and display it at run time (An "About.." type screen).

I'm guessing I need to create some sort of flat file during the Release pipeline, and stuff the file into the drop zip. Then find and load that file/resource via a WebAPI and make the data available to the React app.

Is there some other easier way I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an App Service app setting with the information you want to store. App settings are exposed as environment variables in your application running in an app service.

Comment: Not a bad idea. Easiest way for now. I think I'll store the key info, and then have a API that queries DevOps for the commit annotations and other data.